# uninitialized $_ in array element

Tags: perl, variables, initialization

I have code that contains:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util;
my $index = first { $ARGV[$_] eq "something"; } 0..$#ARGV;
```

but I get

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in array element at a.pl line 4.
```

What could cause this ?

Comment: "minimal" is correct in this case. You don't even mention where the `first` sub comes from, if you use strict and warnings, or anything about ARGV or the rest of your script. Perhaps you should give some more information.

Comment: @TLP: Added some lines about that. ARGV is what contains the command line arguments.

Comment: You should use warnings too, **especially** when debugging. That code should work, though, so you must be doing something in between that is messing you up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your question lacks information, I can only guess at the real problem, but I managed to get a similar error with:

```
C:\perl>perl -MList::Util -we "$a= first { $ARGV[$_] eq 'some' } 0..$#ARGV; print $a" foo bar some thing
Use of uninitialized value $_ in array element at -e line 1.
Can't call method "first" without a package or object reference at -e line 1.
```

The error does not appear if I `use List::Util qw/first/` explicitly, or if I use the full package name: `List::Util::first`. So, my guess is that the `first` function is not properly imported, and does not recognize the list after the code block, leaving `$_` uninitialized.

The error most likely lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I do indeed see that the first list is not imported so that might be it, but I thought that would give me some error about it just as in your example here above or in my test code. But when I get this error that single line about uninitialized variable is all I see.

Comment: That's why we need to see your other code to solve the real problem. Could be something simple.

Comment: That is understandable, but not all source is open and neither can I paste thousands of lines of code, so I had to minimize it somehow.

Comment: @Zitrax, You should minimse it, but the minimised code should demonstrate the problem when run.

Comment: @ikegame, That was my problem, how to reproduce it in a minimal testcase which TLP showed above. If I had reproduced it I would have already known the answer :)

Comment: @Zitrax, (Just luck I saw this because you misspelled my name) Just remove code that's irrelevant until you're left with just the relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with

```
new Class @args
```

That's called the "indirect method notation". It means

```
Class->new(@args)
```

If `first` isn't declared,

```
first { $ARGV[$_] eq "something"; } 0..$#ARGV;
```

is treated as an indirect method call, so it's equivalent to

```
{ $ARGV[$_] eq "something"; }->first(0..$#ARGV);
```

`{ ... }` constructs a hash, which is neither a package name or an object reference as required by a method call, thus

```
Can't call method "first" without a package or object reference
```

The solution: declare `first` by importing it.